# ReactJS: ReactDOM.Render() in a Variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't really find any documentation for this but is it possible to put ReactDOM.Render() in its own render/function variable?

The reason for this is I want to stream line my codebase and when trying to render multiple components with props etc it gets a little messy.

Example:

```js
  ReactDOM.render(
    <SuccessErrorModal status={props.status} progress={50} />,
    document.getElementById("loading-modal")
  );
```

Desired Result:

```js
const LoadingModal = (props) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <SuccessErrorModal status={props.status} progress={50} />,
    document.getElementById("loading-modal")
  );
}

<LoadingModal status={true} /> // Calling the ReactDOM.Render()
```

Create Portal Example (Not working):

```js
const LoadingModal2 = () => {
  ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <SuccessErrorModal status={true} progress={50} />,
    document.getElementById("loading-modal")
  );
};
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ReactDOM.createPortal` for this.

Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

You can get more information [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

Comment: I have tried using Create portal but it doesn't seem to be working. Please see my edit

Comment: Are you getting any error? It should work, if you call the component `LoadingModal2`

Comment: No error at all, im trying to call it by ```<LoadingModal2 />```